# Ant is telling me that my Junit test is successful when it clearly isnt

Tags: ant, junit

I have the following build.xml file

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
  <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" value="classes"/>
  <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
  <property name="test.dir" value="test"/>

  <path id="build.classpath">
      <fileset dir="lib">
       <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <!-- servlet API classes: -->
      <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
          <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
      <pathelement path="${test.dir}"/>
  </path>

 <path id="classpath.base"/>
 <path id="classpath.test">
     <pathelement location="c:/ant/lib/junit.jar" />
     <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
     <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
     <pathelement location="${test.dir}" />
     <pathelement location="classes"/>
    <path refid="classpath.base" />
</path>

<target name="build">
      <!-- Following two lines creat src and test folders in WEB/INF folders -->
      <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${test.dir}"/>
     <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true" deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
      <src path="${src.dir}"/>
      <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
      </javac>
  <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true" deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
          <src path="${test.dir}"/>
          <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
      </javac>
</target>

    <target name="test">
    <junit haltonfailure="true" printsummary="yes">
      <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
      <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
      <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
      <batchtest fork="yes">
            <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
            </fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>
```

and I have the following test class just to test out the build

```
package com.mmz.mvc.test;

import junit.framework.*;

public class MemberDAOTest extends TestCase
{   
    public void test1() {
        assertTrue("Test didn't work",false);
    }
}
```

Obviously this test is supposed to fail, but its not. Can anybody tell me why I am getting the following output. Also, if there is something you see wrong, then please let me know if I can improve my build script, I am new to writing any build files.

```
test:
    [junit] Running com.mmz.mvc.test.MemberDAOTest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.mmz.mvc.test.MemberDAOTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.018 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.018 sec
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: I am sorry but I doubt you are running the test from same file. Can you verify if you have some other version of same file at another location and you are mixing it up?

Comment: what do you mean from the same file?

Comment: I mean as you said, this test should fail. Ant is not doing anything as such that can affect this test. Only thing seems possible to me is that ant is not running test from same folder and there may be some other place where you may have written similar text. You can try running ant in verbose mode using -v at the end and see if you get some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to confirm Ant runs your **latest version of MemberDAOTest**: 
Add method `test2()`, to see if Ant runs `test2()` or not.